# How do I cat a command file?

Tags: shell, shell-script, files

I have the output of the `crontab -l` stored in a file (crontab_file) with no extension. But whenever I try to `cat` it, I get errors saying command not found for multiple line of the file. Here is the code I have so far:

```
file/commands/crontab_file > $PWD/tmp
cat $PWD/tmp
```

I keep getting an error and I don't know why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whenever you post because you "keep getting an error," it would greatly help to include the error you keep getting in your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in your post will execute the file `file/commands/crontab_file` and redirect the standard output to the file `$PWD/tmp`.  When you cat that file you are seeing the output of the execution of the script you called, which was written to that file.  If you want to cat the crontab file, just do it directly `cat file/commands/crontab_file`.

Comment: +1 To clarify slightly: `>` *executes* the file on the left hand side -- it does not copy it.  Since the file wasn't intended to be executed, this produces a list of errors, and that's what's in `$PWD/tmp`.

Comment: Strange that the errors end up in the `tmp` file, as errors should be on stderr, not stdout. Also strange that the `crontab_file` file was set to executable.